# Why don't my migrated Jenkins jobs display after migration from Windows to Linux?

Tags: jenkins, migration, jenkins-2

I recently migrated our windows instance of Jenkins to Linux. This was very easy as I just copied everything from %JENKINS_HOME% to the linux box.

However someone let me know they had their own personal instance of Jenkins that they wanted to rollover to the Linux VM. I copied the jobs folder from their Windows box, to the Linux VM but they dont show up in any of my views (including the ALL view). I also installed the Job Import plugin and it ran successfully as well but I have the same issue.

I'm not sure if I have to modify my config.xml to include these views or if there is another file that I need to merge with my Linux VM. I have also restarted the service and reloaded configuration from disk.

This is on Jenkins 2.0.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I may have missed?

Comment: Did you check the permissions and owner of the job files? I believe they need to have the same owner that your jenkins instance runs under.

Comment: That is exactly what it was. Thank You!

Comment: Add it as answer TheEllis and accept it Mietzner, might help others with similar issues and it wont sow up as unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment of TheEllis:

The copied job files must have the same owner as the jenkins instance runs under. Furthermore read/write/execute permission for the owner should be set, too.

Comment: If I forget the original owner, how to fix this?